# Remote pc connection

Tags: ssh, connection, remote, tunnel

I need to connect to a remote pc from my desktop. My goal is to use an SSH connection to control the remote pc with my desktop. The remote pc and the desktop are in two different networks (behind a NAT or a Router) and they have only private IP. There is a (remote) server with public IP between the remote pc and my desktop.

Server     : can't see remote pc and desktop
Remote Pc  : can see the server
My Desktop : can see the server

How can do this?

Comment: You need to : 1) Know your Desktop/remote PC public addresses (the router's) 2) setup port forwarding on routers and 3) use the public addresses when conencting. Then if that still doesn't work, please provide the commands you use, the resulting logs, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reverse SSH tunnel from your remote machine, e.g.

```
ssh -R 19999:localhost:22 user@server
```

Then from your desktop connect to the server and then connect to port 19999 of the server;

```
ssh user@server
ssh localhost -p 19999
```

You can also combine the second part into a single connection by using a ProxyCommand entry in your ssh config file;

```
Host remote
    HostName server
    ProxyCommand ssh localhost -p 19999
```